# Converting long to byte array

Tags: objective-c, type-conversion

I have java code:

```
Long long_value = 1;
ByteBuffer.allocate( 8).putLong( long_value).array();
```

I have result arrays of bytes: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 (in this order).

Please how correct port this code to Objective C?

Comment: Do you want to store the values in `NSArray`, a plain C array, `NSData`?  Please provide more background on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @sbooth, I need array of chars (bytes) with length 8 in result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Preamble**

You say "in this order". When a multi-byte value is stored in memory the bytes can be stored big-endian - the most significant byte first, or little endian - the least significant byte first. For example the 2-byte hex value 0x1234 is stored as 0x12, 0x34 big-endian and 0x34, 0x12 little-endian. The endian order depends on the computer architecture in use, for example the Intel x86 is little-endian.

`ByteBuffer` is a Java class which stores values as byte according to its own endian flag, independent of the underlying hardware's endian order. The default setting of `ByteBuffer` is big-endian. In your sample you do not set this flag and the array you show is in big endian order.

Apple provides the functions described in [Byte Order Utilities Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFByteOrderUtils/Reference/reference.html) for manipulating endian order. The function you need is `CFSwapInt64HostToBig` which takes a 64-bit signed or unsigned int in whatever endian order the host uses and returns an integer with the bytes arranged in big-endian order - the *numeric* value of the result is effectively meaningless at this point, it is an ordered collection of 8 bytes.

You also say you want 8 bytes, but a `long` may not be 8 bytes long - that depends on the hardware architecture, language and compiler. For example for OS X they are 8 bytes when compiling for 64-bit. There are two ways to address this, you can use the `sizeof` standard function which returns the number of bytes in a value or a type, you pass it a variable or a type name; or you can use the pre-defined sized types when you need a particular number of bytes, for example `SInt64` is the pre-defined 8-byte signed integer type.

Finally you say you want an "array", but what kind of array? Objective-C/Cocoa has two: C language value arrays, and Objective-C object arrays `NSArray` and its mutable sibling `NSMutableArray`.

C language arrays: in C the name of an array variable is of type "pointer to element type", e.g. for the declaration `float values[8]` the type of `values` is `float *`. This means that pointers can be used as arrays, but they are **not** the same thing - a pointer variable holds a pointer to memory but does not allocate memory to point to, an array declaration allocates memory for its elements.

**C Array**

How to get a C "array" of bytes in big-endian order:

```
SInt64 long_value = 0x123456789ABCDEF;              // use SInt64 rather than long
UInt64 BE_value = CFSwapInt64HostToBig(long_value); // use UInt64 as this value may not make numeric sense any more
UInt8 *BE_ptr = (UInt8 *)&BE_value;                 // UInt8 is a byte, take the address of BE_value

// BE_ptr is now a pointer to the 8 bytes of memory occupied by BE_value
// it can be treated as an array
// print it out to demo
for (int ix = 0; ix < 8; ix++)
{
    NSLog(@"%d: %2x", ix, BE_ptr[ix]);
}
```

This will print out `12`, `34` etc.

**Objective-C array**

You can build this on the above. You cannot store a byte directly in an Objective-C object, you must wrap it up as an object using `NSNumber`, and @() is a shorthand to do that:

```
SInt64 long_value = CFSwapInt64HostToBig(0x123456789ABCDEF);
UInt8 *BE_ptr = (UInt8 *)& long_value;

NSMutableArray *BE_array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:8]; // create an object array
for (int ix = 0; ix < sizeof(long); ix++)
{
    [BE_array addObject:@(BE_ptr[ix])]; // @(...) creates an NSNumber
}
NSLog(@"array: %@", BE_array);
```

This will print out the array (in decimal).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You could use a char pointer (chars are the same size as a byte, usually).

```
unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)&myLong;

char byte1 = p[0];
char byte2 = p[1];
//etc...
```